# Combining multiple PostrgreSQL queries

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a query that I have build, the goal is from tags to find associated entities (to create a search bar that will propose entities). I don't want to hardcode it, so my function take an array ["partition", "biography", "masterclass"] as a variable to select where to search.

Bellow an example of a print of my result. It works but I am not satisfied by the fact that I am building 3 different query. I would like to regroup them into one to save time on my query.

I wanted to use the PostgreSQL UNION ALL at first but each select statement must have the same number of fields/columns in the result sets and this is not something I can do.

Would their be a way to do this in a better way.

A dict that I use to create my different query:

```py
   objects = {
        "biography": {
            "table": biography_table,
            "object_id": "biography_id",
            "tag_table": biography_tag_table,
            "entity": Biography,
        },
        "masterclass": {
            "table": masterclass_table,
            "object_id": "masterclass_id",
            "tag_table": masterclass_tag_table,
            "entity": Masterclass,
        },
        "partition": {
            "table": partition_table,
            "object_id": "partition_id",
            "tag_table": partition_tag_table,
            "entity": Partition,
        },
    }
```

My function:

```py
    cte_query = []
    for table in tables:
        object_table = objects[table]["table"]
        object_tag_table = objects[table]["tag_table"]
        object_id = objects[table]["object_id"]

        cte_query.append(
            sa.select(object_table, func.array_agg(tag_table.c.content).label("tags"))
            .select_from(
                object_table.join(
                    object_tag_table,
                    object_table.c.id == object_tag_table.c[object_id],
                ).join(tag_table, tag_table.c.id == object_tag_table.c.tag_id)
            )
            .group_by(object_table.c.id)
            .cte(f"{table}_cte")
        )

    cte_partition, cte_biography, cte_masterclass = cte_query
    print(cte_partition)
    print(cte_biography)
    print(cte_masterclass)

    partition = sa.select(cte_partition).where(
        func.lower(func.array_to_string(cte_partition.c.tags, ",")).like(
            func.lower(f"%{search}%")
        )
    )
    masterclass = sa.select(cte_masterclass).where(
        func.lower(func.array_to_string(cte_masterclass.c.tags, ",")).like(
            func.lower(f"%{search}%")
        )
    )
    biography = sa.select(cte_biography).where(
        func.lower(func.array_to_string(cte_biography.c.tags, ",")).like(
            func.lower(f"%{search}%")
        )
    )
    result = []
    result.append(conn.execute(partition).fetchall())
    result.append(conn.execute(masterclass).fetchall())
    result.append(conn.execute(biography).fetchall())

    print(result)
```

And an example of a result:

```yaml
[[],
[(UUID('61fa9287-fd5b-49fc-8e91-037f6343b46d'), UUID('12345648-1234-1234-1234-123456789123'), 'masterclass', None, None, None, None, None, ['violon', 'flute'], 'created', datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 19, 21, 41, 55, 556527), None, UUID('12345648-1234-1234-1234-123456789123'), None, ['masterclass', 'violon', 'flute'])],
[(UUID('9bb75325-ad82-4170-908b-179e6fadd8b6'), 'flute', 'Boby', ['statement'], 'Française', 'http://www.gaines-johnson.com/', ['bag'], 'Number five region no power look. Energy government financial. Leave present nice.', 'compositor', 'created', None, datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 21, 14, 45, 19, 220057), None, UUID('12345648-1234-1234-1234-123456789123'), None, ['flute', 'boby', 'flute boby', 'statement'])]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `conn.execute` to run the queries that you're building; that's the point where the `UNION` needs to be executed instead. To construct it, use SQLAlchemy's [`union`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union) function.

In this case, you should be able to say `union(partition, masterclass, biography)`; if you want to make it more extensible, you could construct a list of the queries based on user input and pass it to the function as `union(*queries)`.

Comment: I wanted to do that at first but sadely I get this error:
```python
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: All selectables passed to CompoundSelect must have identical numbers of columns; select #1 has 8 columns, select #2 has 15
```

Comment: Naturally, the columns that you select will have to be of the same shape. For example, if you select `(id, name)` for one table then you'll have to select `(id, name)` for the others. This is necessary for `UNION` in SQL as well. If some columns don't occur in some tables, you can use `NULL as column` to "widen" the result set.

Comment: In this case, I'll try to find another way as the result had really different shapes.